# How can I get started using Donald Knuth's MIX/MMIX assembler?

Tags: knuth, taocp, mmix

I'd like to be able to learn MIX/MMIX, but I don't know the toolchain that one would use to write it. I've used uVision in the past for ARM assembler related things, does such an equivalent exist for MIX/MMIX?

Answer (score 5):

[GNU MDK](https://www.gnu.org/software/mdk/) is a nice free implementation. It includes an assembler, a virtual machine, a virtual machine GUI, and even an embedded Scheme interpreter for writing scripts. It also has really nice integration with Emacs.

Answer (score 2):

Link: https://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~knuth/mmix.html

The link is a refernce to the offical site of Donald Knuths MMIX

he also wrote a book which is part of the Art of Programming series you can buy this for nearly 15 € on amazon.

But the Book is not so easy.

If you are able to read german you can also buy the Book MMIX from Martin Ruckert or Axel Böttcher

Hope this anwsers your Questions

Good Luck :D